# Android ListView section header

Tags: android

Are there any built-in ways for creating Android `ListView` section headers? If not what is the easiest way for doing so, using XML markup as far as possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a header view? : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: I think this is for a single header. I want multiple headers in a single ListView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can make your own implementation or use a third-party library. I suggest you to use this one in case you want them to stick at the top of the list:

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score 1):

You can add several headers using [addHeaderView (View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29). Your views are then handled by a [HeaderViewListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html)

Comment: It seems addHeaderView() is for adding header(s) at the top of the list, but not for section headers.